# How to create a Secret using Google Cloud Secret Manager with gcloud command line tool?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

I have started a Google Cloud Account and I want to access and use Google Secret Manager. How can I create a Secret using Google Secret Manager API using gcloud command line interface ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see it here https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets#secretmanager-create-secret-cli

```
gcloud secrets create secret-id \
    --replication-policy="automatic"
```